# Logisitic regression cutoff point + evaluate misclassified instances

Tags: regression, logistic, weka

I have created a logistic regression model in the explorer in Weka which can classify between three classes.

When there are two classes it takes a 50% cutoff values, but I was wondering how it works with three classes. Each model is seperate and the highest probability is chosen?

Additionally I am wondering: I would like to see which of the instances are misclassified. Is there an easy way to do this from the interface? Or do I need to use the java library?

Comment: The intent of polytomous logistic regression is to estimate event probabilities.  Don't use any method that relies on thresholds.

Comment: Legend has it that if you threshold the output of a logistic regression, @FrankHarrell will appear and tell you about proper scoring rules, any time, any place.

Comment: Some legends are true ...

Comment: Agreed that it estimates probabilities. I am wondering in weka, based on which treshold the confusion matrix is calculated. Or are they just classified according to highest probability?